# gapi.client.init() promise returns nothing

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

The following has happened to me three times now:

1. I set up a new project on the google api console to use with the google drive api,
2. I use it, it seemingly works well,
3. All of a sudden, the gapi.client.init() promise is no longer fulfilled or rejected - nothing is returned.

Does anyone know why this may happen?

**Edit:**
As a commenter has asked, here are the logs from the api console dashboard. The purple lines are for the drive api.
[image: The purple lines are for the drive api.]
**Edit:** It seems there is some sort of traffic coming to google from something named "compute", every time i make a request. On the image above, "compute" are the orange lines. I've just made an attempt to make a request again, and these popped up on the logs:[image]
What is this compute thing??

Comment: Can you paste your logs from the dashboard here?
Maybe you can find some clues about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just discovered what might be the solution to this. As the user rsolomon on [github](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/392) pointed out, this could be due to a bug with chrome dev tools, and it was for me! Having dev tools open made the init fail silently. If anyone else is having this problem, try closing your dev tools.